# How can I use the contextual menu key to insert a bullet or number list?

Tags: keyboard, microsoft-word-2013, bullets

I moved from using Word 2003 to 2013 with a brief spell using 2007 and 2010. The more Word becomes intuitive, the less it enables users to do what they used to be able to do with keyboard shortcuts.

I miss my old (yet hyper efficient) 2003 contextual menu that only required 3 steps to transform a word/sentence/text into a list item or bullet/number list in a flash, while typing text.

context menu Key + B + ENTER

[image]

Is there any way to do this through 100% keyboard steps in Word 2013 / Office365? i know I could just as Well create a keyboard shortcut for this but WHY have Microsoft removed this feature in the context menu ? Are they hidden somewhere else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + SHIFT + L is the shortcut to make the selected text a bulleted list.  I don't think there is direct keyboard shortcut for Numbered list though.

Numbered list, *can* be accomplished through these keystrokes (although it's obviously not ideal)

Alt + H to bring up the key tips for the Home tab of the ribbon
Then press N to select Numbered List:

[image: Word ribbon after pressing Alt + H]

After that, you can use the arrow or tab keys to choose the numbered list format and hit ENTER to select

[image: Numbered list format options]